# AppBarButton Command in MVVM does not Trigger RelayCommand

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I have Windows Phone Class Library that uses the MVVM model. In my `Generic.xaml` I have the Style for my `CustomElementControl.cs` that has a `CustomElementViewModel.cs`. I also have a `ViewModelLocator.cs` that relates ViewModels to Controls that is named in this context as Locator, but that is not relevant to this case. Now, if I add a Command to a Button like so:

```
<Style TargetType="view:CustomElementControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="view:CustomElementControl">
                <Page x:Name="pageRoot" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=view:CustomElementViewModel, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <TextBlock Text="something" Foreground="{Binding Path=ColorTest}" />
                    <Button Content="MyButton" Command="{Binding MultiSelectCommand}" />
                </Page>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And catch in the `CustomElementViewModel.cs` like so:

```
private RelayCommand _multiSelectCommand;
public RelayCommand MultiSelectCommand {
    get {
        if(_multiSelectCommand == null) {
            _multiSelectCommand = new RelayCommand(
            () => {
                this.SelectionMode = (this.SelectionMode == ListViewSelectionMode.Single) ? ListViewSelectionMode.Multiple : ListViewSelectionMode.Single;
            });
        }
        return _multiSelectCommand;
    }
}
```

It works fine, however, if I want to add the Command event to an AppBarButton like so:

```
<Style TargetType="viewCustomElementControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="view:CustomElementControl">
                <Page x:Name="pageRoot" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=view:CustomElementViewModel, Mode=TwoWay}">
                        <TextBlock Text="something" Foreground="{Binding Path=ColorTest}" />
                    </Page>
                    <Page.BottomAppBar>
                        <CommandBar>
                            <AppBarButton Icon="AllApps" Label="multiselect" Command="{Binding MultiSelectCommand}" />
                        </CommandBar>
                    </Page.BottomAppBar>
                </Page>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The RelayCommand is never triggered. What am I missing here?

**UPDATE**
I've even tried setting the DataContext of the AppBarButton like so:

```
<AppBarButton Icon="AllApps" Label="multiselect" Command="{Binding DataContext.MultiSelectCommand, ElementName=pageRoot, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

And

```
<AppBarButton Icon="AllApps" Label="multiselect" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=CustomElementViewModel, Mode=TwoWay} Command="{Binding MultiSelectCommand}" />
```

And none works.

**UPDATE 2**
Here's a sample: http://1drv.ms/1vRnaYH

Comment: I don't know what is the Locator in your DataContext binding, but in your third snippet you don't put view:CustomElementViewModel like in the first snippet, you just put CustomElementViewModel. Could that cause a problem?

Comment: It was a copy paste error, it is now corrected. I also added an explanation for the Locator you mentioned.

Comment: If you set the DataContext of the AppBarButton directly with the same DataContext as your page just as a test, does it work?

Comment: I tried setting the DataContext in two different ways and none of them worked. I've updated my question.